# Auto Hide/Show DIV in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am beginner to asp.net . i need to alert the currently logged in user as new message arrived in the right bottom page . How can i do this

Comment: Add more details to your question.

Comment: How to do what? You forgot to post your HTML, Javascript and explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: your question title says to hide/show div ? and in explanation you write how to show mesng ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have created a div that contains controls relating to the users inbox, or a custom message.

Firstly, I suggest putting the controls in an asp:Panel, and not a . This is so you can hide and show the panel at any time.

Force the panel to be hidden on page load. Then, create a method in Page_Load or Page_Init to check when the user has a Message. If so, make the panel visible.

I am assuming you have the messages stored in some kind of DB (Database). If so, create a new column to the PrivateMessage table to save weather the user has read the PM or not. This will allow you to easily distinguish when to show the asp:Panel.

Use a float tag for the asp:Panel, then position it wherever you want it on the screen.

Without any of your source, or any information, this is the best I can give.

Answer (score 0):

to do this you can use notification see this url
http://www.magic-dev.com/send-notification-signalr.htm